# Joda time manipulation

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a use case to make time go faster i.e. I want to change the clock by a factor (positive int). So, if I change it by a factor of 2, then 1 second will have 500 millis and 1 minute will have 30 seconds and so on.

How do I achieve this in jodatime ?

Comment: If one second is 500ms, and one minute is 30s, then one minute is 15000ms, a quarter of what it used to be - probably not what you meant. Can you expand on your use case, because it sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right now.

Comment: My use case is that I have to make time go faster. So, it is like devising a new clock, so 1 second of new clock is 500 milliseconds of actual clock. And hence, 1 minute of new clock is 30 seconds of actual clock. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: 30 seconds are not 15000ms, and his question is pretty clear : he needs a factor for time increments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since when are you going to be doubling time?

For example if you use

```
import org.joda.time;

Instant doubleTime(Instant instant) {
    return new Instant(instant.getMillis() * 2);
}
```

you just doubled time since the epoch back in 1970.

You likely want to choose when time should start doubling.

```
Instant doubleTime(Instant start, Instant end) {
    Long s = start.getMillis();
    Long e = end.getMillis();

    return new Instant((e - s) * 2 + s);
}
```

That will let you double the end time since the start time.

This same trick can be done more simply with Duration:

```
Duration doubleTime(Duration duration) {
    return new Duration(duration.getMillis() * 2);
}
```

This is simpler since a Duration has no idea when it started or ended.  Just how long it was.

Keep in mind time is never simple.  A whole bunch of subtle things get ignored when you do things like this.  Leap years, leap seconds, etc.  If that's what you want it's fine but don't act surprised if doubling one year doesn't perfectly give you two years.